# Would you like to be a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

> **[The election has now been officially announced.](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/501/79)**
> See that page for any further details.

---

We just got word that a moderator election is coming our way pretty soon.
This is an informal inquiry:
**Would you be willing to run for a moderator's position?**

I will post "polling answers" below so that you can express your view anonymously by voting.
But feel free to also post an answer yourself; just a short response like "I'll seriously consider running" will do.

If you think someone else might be good, write a comment below and I can ping them to make sure they see this.
The purpose of this post is to gauge community interest, not to make any formal decisions or commitments.

Some relevant meta posts you may or may not want to consult:

- [Three *pro tempore* moderators were appointed at the very start.](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176/79)
- [One stepped down](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/79) and [two continued](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/423/79).
- [The duties and workload of a Latin moderator are not very heavy.](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478/79)

Feel free to discuss in comments or [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36130/conloqvivm).

Comment: I have locked this question so that the votes to the answers below represent the situation at the time when the election was officially announced. Any further discussion should be taken to that meta post or a new one. (The formal reason for locking is not descriptive; the selection did not include this purpose.)

Answer (score 8):

Vote this up if this describes your position:

> I will probably not run, but I look forward to seeing the candidates and voting.

Answer (score 3):

Vote this up if this describes your position:

> I will seriously consider running for a moderator's position.

Answer (score 1):

Vote this up if this describes your position:

> I will run to be a moderator.