# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Latin Language Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://latin.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **April 19** to bring in two more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on April 19, users can [nominate themselves](https://latin.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On April 26, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on May 4.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: Is there a term involved, as the Latin _pro tempore_ suggests? Sorry, I don't know if it has a different connotation in English, and I failed to find an explanation in the MSE announcement

Comment: There isn't a term. The main difference is that moderators on Beta sites are only moderators while the site is in Beta (hence the pro tempore); once the site is out of Beta, the first "full" election is run, and at that point moderators are generally "for life" (we have some policies surrounding misconduct or inactivity, but that aside, they're "for life"). Once that first "full" election happens, any pro tempore mods will need to re-run if they want to keep their mod status.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The current two moderators are continuing and we are getting two new ones, so the team will soon have four moderators.
Running the daily moderation business doesn't require all that much workforce, so there are many possible roles a new moderator can take:

- welcoming and instructing new users
- participating in moderator conversations
- curating the content by editing posts and comments
- being active and helpful in the public chat
- and much more

My point is:
**You are more than welcome to join the moderator team even if you are only interested in some of these roles!**
If you dislike, say, approaching difficult users or participating on meta, you can focus on other things.
Moderators can differ from each other in many ways.