# What would you like to ask of your moderator candidates?

Tags: discussion, election

[The questionnaire is now live!](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/519/79)
I will leave this question open so that any new ideas can be proposed and voted on if anyone has thoughts before the next election.

---

[A moderator election is about to take place](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/501/79), and it is time to think whether we want any kind of debates, campaigns, or anything else in that spirit.
[The election pages](https://latin.stackexchange.com/election/1) will handle the formal side of things, mostly automatically.
It is up to us to decide whether we want supporting activities.

I propose that we ask all candidates to answer a short questionnaire with questions chosen by our users.
Propose questions for this purpose below, **one question per answer**.
We will include all suggested questions with **score 3 or higher** (or at least 4 and at most 10 questions) in the final questionnaire.
Feel free to suggest anything!

I also added a ["meta answer"](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/a/504/79) below, allowing you to vote whether you would like to see such a questionnaire.

Answer (score 4):

Question suggestion:

> What is your relation with the Latin language? What role does it play in your studies, work, leisure, or other life?

Answer (score 4):

Question suggestion:

> How have you acted as a moderator so far? Moderation can mean using the review queues, voting to close and reopen, participating on meta, flagging, editing, welcoming new users, or something else.

Rationale:
The best proof of future actions are the past actions.
Many forms of moderation are accessible to all users of high reputation.
It would strike me as weird to say that someone will start moderating if they are elected a moderator but have not done anything in that direction yet.

Answer (score 4):

Question suggestion:

> What kind of a role would you take as a moderator?

Rationale:
See my answer to [the election announcement](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/501/79).
We don't need all moderators to use all the moderator tools and to take part in everything.
Different moderators can take different roles.

Answer (score 2):

This is a meta answer about the questionnaire itself.
This will not be included in the questionnaire.

**Vote this up if you would like to see every candidate answer a questionnaire on meta.**
Vote this down if you find it useless.

If the final score ends up negative, the questionnaire will not be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Question suggestion:

> Why do you want to be a moderator of the Latin stack exchange?

Answer (score 1):

Question suggestion:

> What do you think should be changed about the way this site is moderated?