# Latin SE election is coming. Do you want to become a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

**UPDATE:** Given the level of interest expressed thus far, the Community Team has scheduled the election to start on August 8th. See a full timeline on [this post](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/607/6).

---

The community team is considering running a graduation election on our site. A graduation election would have four moderator positions available, and current moderators would need to nominate themselves and win in order to keep their status. The election would not increase the total number of moderators: it might just replace some of the current ones. The graduation election also would not imply other changes related to graduation.

Out of the current team [two moderators were appointed without an election at the beginning](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176/79) and [two were elected last year](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/528/79). After the graduation election all moderators would have the same mandate and be elected by the users.

The election will only be run if there are at least five candidates running. This ensures that the election is comptetitive and the voters have a genuine choice. The goal of this post is to gauge whether there would be enough candidates.

**If you would be willing to volunteer as a moderator, please post an answer here or let us know in some other way.** If it looks like we could have a competitive election, we will inform the community team and hopefully have a graduation election soon.

#### Timeline

The expected timeline is as follows:

- Week of Aug 8: Question collection begins. (See [our questions from last time](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/503/79).)
- Week of Aug 15: Nominations begin. (Every candidate has to formally nominate themselves in the election system.)
- Next week: A preliminary election if there are over ten candidates. Skipped otherwise.
- Next wee: Election.
- Around end of August: Results.

The expected time of the election is late July or early August. We will keep you updated as things get more specific.

The election can be canceled if not enough people express their willingness to run.

#### What a moderator does

Running the daily moderation business doesn't require all that much workforce, so there are many possible roles a new moderator can take:

- welcoming and instructing new users
- participating in moderator conversations
- curating the content by editing posts and comments
- being active and helpful in the public chat
- and much more

My point is:
**You are more than welcome to join the moderator team even if you are only interested in some of these roles!**
If you dislike, say, approaching difficult users or participating on meta, you can focus on other things.
Moderators can differ from each other in many ways.

If you want to know more about the responsibilities of a moderator, [consult this meta question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/478/79) or ask any of the present ones.

(This statement is [a repeat from our last election announcement](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/501/79) and still holds true.)

#### Nomination procedure

[Last time](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/495/79) this was asked anonymously.
Let me know if you would prefer that.

What we have here are not formal nominations, but just informal declarations of interest.
You do not commit to anything by saying you might run, and positions between a hard "yes" and a hard "no" are of course welcome.
It's important to get some expressions of interest; if too few seem to want to run, there will be no election.

Comment: Considering that you just posted this now, and it's almost July already, I don't think an August election is appropriate, but that's just me.

Comment: @user1271772 Fair enough, it comes pretty quick. The weeks offered to us by the community team are in July and August, so I guess this is the timescale of how these things work. Local moderators don't decide the timing. On the other hand, we it was announced upon our graduation that an election would be likely to come in 2022 or maybe 2023, so I hope some have given this some thought before today's announcement.

Comment: If the diamond mods on a site explain to the CMs that they want the election to happen later, the CMs will most likely comply. Whoever gets elected is going to be given the opportunity to be a "moderator for life" except in extreme circumstances (e.g. a mod gets voted out by all other mods, or they get removed because they did something **extremely** outrageous). Therefore, this election is a pretty serious thing and shouldn't be taken lightly. If an election occurs in August, I can't really say it would be a fair election. This site has 7.6k users. On average, how many times/month they visit?

Comment: I don't think August is too soon considering the site graduated several months back. I also think having a couple of weeks at most to add yourself as a nominee seems adequate. Moderators should be regulars of the site and engaged so any contenders should see it pretty quick.

Answer (score 3):

At least the following users are planning to run:

- Adam
- Cerberus
- cmw
- Draconis
- Joonas Ilmavirta

---

The list above is in alphabetical order.
All names are collected in a single answer so that we can't vote on the candidates yet.

Please edit your name in if you are planning to run, whether or not the plan is final!